# Change all values that satisfy different conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

```
     A      B  C   D
0  foo    one  0   0
1  bar    one  1   2
2  foo    two  2   4
3  pak  three  3   6
4  foo    two  4   8
5  bar    two  5  10
6  foo    one  6  12
7  dop  three  7  14
8  foo    one  0   0
9  bar    one  1   2
10 pak    two  2   4
11 bar  three  3   6
```

I need to multiply C and D columns with a weight but weight are different for A column values. For foo it's 2, for bar it's 1,5, and for pak it's 3,4 and for dop it's 2,3. In reality those conditions are 15 and the data is huge so I can't use for loop.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "can't use for loop"...something somewhere has to loop to over your data to execute these operations.  IMO you should make a new column that has your multiplier value and multiply that new column by C and D

Comment: I meant that if I use for loops it will take a very long time, I just wanted to know is there a way to do that in pandas or numpy for it to be faster

Comment: Well pandas/numpy can multiply two series in an element by element fashion with relative speed.  So my original comment remains where you need to create a new column that has your desired multiplier value, you can loop over the existing df and create a new column or in your data generation process that creates this just do the mapping there and forgo the `A` column as it exists currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
conditions = {
    'foo': 2,
    'bar': 1.5,
    'pak': 3.4,
    'dop': 2.3

}

weights = df['A'].map(conditions)

df['result'] = df['C'] * df['D'] * weights
```